# Posicionar objetos en HTML y CSS

Tags: html

Necesito crear una pagina para un trabajo en el colegio, y necesito poner los créditos al final de la pagina, solo tengo permitido hacerlo con html o css en el bloc de notas.

De momento esta es mi pagina de Inicio.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gray;  // color de fondo menu
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white; // color de la letra del menu
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: black; //sombra menu
}

html {
  background-color: #4690FF; // color de fondo pagina web
}
#bloqueprincipal {

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #c8e5e3;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}"
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <link href="estilo/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 
<title> Home </title>
 <link rel="icon" href="imagenes/ducha.png" type="image/png">
 </head>

 
  <body>
  <div align="center"><img src="imagenes/wall.jpg" width="100%" height="40%"> </div>
  
  <ul>
  <li> <a href="biografia.html"> Biografia </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="musica.html"> Música </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgJgI7h0j0k"> Un ratón con una botella xd </a> </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="bloqueprincipal">
  <h1 align="center">Inicio</h1>
  <center>
  Bienvenido/a a mi página web, en ella encontrarás varios datos sobre mi, los cuales incluyen: Una breve <a href="biografia.html"> biografía</a> mia, una proyección de lo que me interesa a <a href="babo.html">futuro</a> 
  en cuanto a empleo, Una seleccion de mi <a href="musica.html"> música</a> favorita y por ultimo estará la opcion de ver dos videos realizados en la clase de informatica, un <a href="video.html">Thriller</a> y una <a href="video.html"> comedia</a>.
  <br>Y por ultimo tambien veran <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgJgI7h0j0k"> Un ratón con una botella </a><br>
<br><BR><BR><BR><BR><br><br><BR><BR><BR><BR><br><br><BR><BR><BR><BR><br><br><BR><BR><BR><BR><br><br><BR><BR><BR>Miguel Mondaca | 2018 | All rights reserved<br>
  </div>
  </center>
  </body>

  



</html>
```

De momento llevo esto, como pueden ver, la solución que ocupo es la de poner
 hasta que llegue el texto al fondo, pero posiblemente esa solución sea rechazada por mi profesor, conoce alguno de ustedes algún método de enviar el texto directamente al fondo?

Comment: Si sólo tienes permitida hacer la web con "Bloc de Notas", entonces, te recomiendo que repases algo de html básico que puedes buscar en google o youtube, lo mismo con css. Para la parte de los créditos, con lo que aprendas de los vídeos o mini cursos que hay en la red, podrás hacerlo. También, podrías agregar para que quede "mejor" algo de javascript o php y podrás quedar mejor :)

Comment: Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. Lee [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías implementar el tag

```
<footer></footer>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_footer.asp

Y añadirle un poco de estilos para posicionarlo al fondo de la página

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Al final lo que quieres hacer quedaria como lo siguiente

```
<html>

<head>
    <link href="estilo/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title> Home </title>
    <link rel="icon" href="imagenes/ducha.png" type="image/png">
</head>

<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

html {
  background-color: #4690FF;
}

#bloqueprincipal {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c8e5e3;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
 </style>

<body>
    <div align="center"><img src="imagenes/wall.jpg" width="100%" height="40%"></div>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="biografia.html"> Biografia </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="musica.html"> Música </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgJgI7h0j0k"> Un ratón con una botella xd </a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="bloqueprincipal">
        <h1 align="center">Inicio</h1>
        <center>
            Bienvenido/a a mi página web, en ella encontrarás varios datos sobre mi, los cuales incluyen: Una breve <a
                href="biografia.html"> biografía</a> mia, una proyección de lo que me interesa a <a href="babo.html">futuro</a>
            en cuanto a empleo, Una seleccion de mi <a href="musica.html"> música</a> favorita y por ultimo estará la
            opcion de ver dos videos realizados en la clase de informatica, un <a href="video.html">Thriller</a> y una
            <a href="video.html"> comedia</a>.
            <br>Y por ultimo tambien veran <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgJgI7h0j0k"> Un ratón con una
                botella </a>
        </center>

    </div>
    <footer>
        Miguel Mondaca | 2018 | All rights reserved
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```